# cocoa pods xcode 5 Product -> Profile shows up warning and errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a xcode5 workspace using cocoapods,

However when i want to profile it using Product -> Profile it's shows error like this image screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7FB4.jpg

Any ideas how to fix these?
Thank you

Comment: Are you able to build but not profile your app?

Answer (score 1):

I've had something similar happen with some of the libraries in the workspace not being built. 
Go to build settings of your product and in the search bar type "Build active architecture only". If it says "YES" change it. do it for the other projects inside your workspace. 
Hope this helps